# How can i add TrimString Middleware in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Just came to know that Laravel 5.4 has an awesome feature **TrimString**, which removes the white spaces from any input. I want this middleware in my 5.3 project, any idea how to do that?

I just copied the middleware from GitHub repo of Laravel but it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use this feature in `Laravel 5.3`.

Add these two classes into your `App\Http\Middleware`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php

Updating it's `namespace` to `App\Http\middleware`.
Like:

**TransformsRequest.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

class TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * The additional attributes passed to the middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = [];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;

        $this->clean($request);

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Clean the request's data.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function clean($request)
    {
        $this->cleanParameterBag($request->query);

        $this->cleanParameterBag($request->request);

        if ($request->isJson()) {
            $this->cleanParameterBag($request->json());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clean the data in the parameter bag.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag  $bag
     * @return void
     */
    protected function cleanParameterBag(ParameterBag $bag)
    {
        $bag->replace($this->cleanArray($bag->all()));
    }

    /**
     * Clean the data in the given array.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return array
     */
    protected function cleanArray(array $data)
    {
        return collect($data)->map(function ($value, $key) {
            return $this->cleanValue($key, $value);
        })->all();
    }

    /**
     * Clean the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function cleanValue($key, $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return $this->cleanArray($value);
        }

        return $this->transform($key, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

**TrimStrings.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class TrimStrings extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->except)) {
            return $value;
        }

        return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
    }
}
```

And add into your `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
];
```

To use it just use:

```
dd(request('email'));
```

More on it:

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-middleware

Comment: "I want this middleware in my 5.3 project" - why do you suggest to upgrade to 5.4?

Comment: @JohnDeep I have not yet tested but you could add these two classes and try running the `TrimString` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php

Comment: @OlegArkhipov If you want to use it, just updated the answer after the trial.