# Laravel 5.3 Update record. Only update changed record and leave the unchanged record

Tags: php, http, sql-update, laravel-5.3

[image][image]I want to update a profile and when I update the record, the old data that I didnot change is also updated.

I want to update only those values that are changed. Unchanged values should not be updated.

Route:

```
Route::post('/profile/settings/{user}', 'Admin\userController@UpdateProfileSettings')->name('profile.settings');
```

Controller Method:

```
 public function UpdateProfileSettings(Request $request, User $user)
{

    if (auth()->user()->id == $user->id) {

        $user->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'qualification' => $request->qualification,
            'institute' => $request->institute,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'speciality' => $request->speciality,
            'address' => $request->address,
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();
    } else {
        abort(403, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you don't send the unchanged data, am i right ?

Comment: How can I check it? User can edit any field.

Comment: I meant what are the values of $request->field if it's not changed.. 
var_dump the values and show it here.

Comment: Use old(<field name>) function in value attribute in every form field, it will fill inputs with data, and when you will save data that not changed it just replace old data with old(untouched data) and changed data will be replace old.

Comment: I am doing the same. But i am saving only unique emails. If user changes it profile and saves it then duplicate email error is thrown.

Comment: I dont want to save it again that is already saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
$name = $request->input('name', $user->name);
```

For laravel 5.4 :
Also makesure that  `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middlewares in your application's global middleware stack found inside `App\Http\Kernel`

For laravel 5.3, you can manually add these middle-wares, to your project..
Adding `TrimgStrings` is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845818/how-can-i-add-trimstring-middleware-in-laravel-5-3).

Adding `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` will follow the same steps..

Create a new file `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
class ConvertEmptyStringsToNull extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return is_string($value) && $value === '' ? null : $value;
    }
}
```

2. Register the middleware as global by adding into your `App\Http\Kernel.php`

   ```
   protected $middleware = [
   \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middlewar\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
   \App\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest::class,
   \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
   \App\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
   ];
   ```

Comment: There is something wrong with formatting, not sure if it's related to stackoverflow or my browser (vivaldi).